# How to kill a process started via system() when using R?

Tags: r, system

I'm running another program using the `system()` function in R.  I'm feeding in command line features for the other program.  When I miscode the parameters, I'll get an error message that I can't delete the associated file because it's still being controlled by the program I called in the `system()` call.

Is there a way to manually kill these types of processes besides restarting R which is what I'm currently doing?

An example would be something like:

```
system("python myFile.py")
```

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: (If on a linux/mac) You can find the process id and just type `kill -9 pid` (where `pid` is the number for that process)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you can use `TASKKILL` command to kill a process.

E.g.

```
TASKKILL /IM python*
```